# RAID Drive on Dell Perc H310 RAID controller not recognized

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, disk

So, I recently bought a Dell Perc H310 RAID controller to put in a Fujitsu Esprimo P700 E85+ Computer running Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS. The Motherboard seems to have no UEFI, just a BIOS. From a hardware perspective I:

- connected a 500GB Boot drive straight onto the MoBo
- connected 2*3TB SATA drives through a SATA to mini-SAS cable splitter to the RAID controller
- configured a Raid0, RAID1 Virtual Drive in the Boot-Configuration-BIOS

and everything seems fine in the Controller's menu.

But when I boot Ubuntu (it's installed on the Boot HDD) the 6TB, 3TB RAID drive (RAID0 and 1 respectively) is nowhere to be found, nor any of the 2*3TB separate drives it consists of.

I used `parted --list` and `lsblk` to check for the drive(s) and `lspci` to check the controller.

The ouput of `lsblk` is:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5328
loop1    7:1    0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part
└─sda2   8:2    0 465.8G  0 part /
```

The output of `parted --list` is:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5000AAKX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number Start End Size File system Name Flags
1 1049kB 2097kB 1049kB bios_grub
2 2097kB 500GB 500GB ext4
```

The output of `lspci` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family IDE-r Controller (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon] (rev 03)
```

And the output of `lspci -vv` for the RAID controller is:

```
01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon]
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
Region 0: I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Region 1: Memory at fe460000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Region 3: Memory at fe400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
Expansion ROM at fe440000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: megaraid_sas
```

**Note:** I also tried the RAID Ctrlr on a Windows machine, with a UEFI. It did not POST with the card, until I taped over PCIe lanes B5 and B6 (I found this advice somewhere online). After that, it did recognize a RAID0 configuration. Moving the card and disks back to the Ubuntu System and booting it there brought no success either. The controller behaves exactly as before, which is why I haven't removed the tape over the two lanes yet.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82614/discussion-on-question-by-pulp-user-virtual-raid5-drive-of-dell-perc-h310-not-re).

Comment: Djeez, even with a bounty you're not having much success!  And you've got 65 views so far....

Comment: I decided, since I still have that option, to return the raid card and run a software raid for now. That sort of makes this question obsolete, since I could not try any new answers. Should I delete the question, or can a moderator close it, or do I just leave it open? I want to thank you again for your help!

Comment: I'll talk to a mod about recovering the bounty. As for the question itself, I would leave it up for the moment.  I'll have it closed afterwards for "Cannot be reproduced"